# Julia supports dynamic "expando object" a la C#?

Tags: julia, dynamic-typing

In C# is possible to have a dynamic object with fields defined at runtime using expando objects. Example:

```
dynamic contact = new ExpandoObject();
contact.Name = “Patrick Hines”;
contact.Phone = “206-555-0144”;
```

As you can see, the *contact* object is dynamic, in the sense we can set fields in the object, without declaring previously the structure of the object. I understand in Julia we can have a parameter/variable without declared type, as in:

```
function setProp1(obj) obj.prop1=1 end
```

But, as i understand it, the *obj* object must be created from a type with a field prop1. If prop1 is not declared somewhere as a field, *setProp1* can't set dynamically the field *prop1*. If i want full dynamism, and i want not to worry for performance, there is a way to create "expando objects" in Julia?

Comment: [This page](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/noteworthy-differences/) suggests using a [`dict`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/stdlib/collections/#Base.Dict).  *"Julia’s types do not support dynamically adding fields at runtime."*

Comment: I hope someday a more convenient syntax will be created. A syntax a la expando object may help peaple coming from python or other full dynamic languages.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you linked old doc (0.4) stable one (0.6 now) is ->  https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/noteworthy-differences/ (for example there are documented 12 differences from Python in 0.4 and only 10 in 0.6) pls edit your comment and I will remove mine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is currently not possible to dynamically create new fields simply by assigning to undefined field names.  It may be possible in the future with a feature like [#1974: allow overloading of a.b field access syntax](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1974).  Note, though, that it's currently tagged in the Julia 2.0+ milestone; it is not a high priority and may or may not ever happen.

It is possible to create a macro that changes field access into dict-like syntax, such that `@expando contact.Name = "foo"` is transformed into `contact[:Name] = "foo"`, but it's probably better and easier just to use dictionaries and the indexing syntax directly.